# Misspelled words or Typo Mistakes handling in Elastic Search without fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

We are working on an ecommerce product with Next JS and Python API driven. In this we have implemented Elasticsearch (version 8) Rest based API calls from React JS.

We are facing a problem as below,
Spelling Mistakes to be handled without fuzziness.

**For example:** **`flour tiels`** should **only match** **`floor tiles`**. This should **not match** below items

- floor mats
- wooden floor
- floor carpet
- virtrified tiles
- wall tiles
- Kitchen tiles

So in this case, We are unable to use fuzziness, We have tried with nGrams option but it was not helpful.

Any other suggestion to handle this would a great support for us, Thank you all !